# Android Align TextView between two dividers horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is how I tried:

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padd_loading_btn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padd_loading_btn" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orLoginWithEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/orlogin_withEmail"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

This looks ok for my HD display but for others it looks awful.

How do I make the text wrap as much as it needs, and then the dividers equally align on sides?

p.s. Of course I can set a relative layout and inside to put a divider to fill in width and the textview with a white background above with padding, but i don't think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padd_loading_btn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padd_loading_btn" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orLoginWithEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/orlogin_withEmail"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me, so thank you! But I think you should add: `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code, you can change TextViews to view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:background="#cccccc" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:text="Hello Android" />


    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:background="#cccccc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a FrameLayout, remember to set the width of the back view to "match_parent" and the background of the TextView to null or white and give your TextView paddingLeft and paddingRight to achieve the effect you want

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padd_loading_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padd_loading_btn" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orLoginWithEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/orlogin_withEmail"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </FrameLayout>
```